# Estimated marginal means, controlling for the effect of only one IV level (emmeans, lmer)

Tags: r, lme4, interaction, contrast, emmeans

I have an experiment with 2 IVs, time (3 levels, t1, t2, t3, within subject), and correction type (3 levels, between subject). DV = attitude (continuous). The complete lmer model looks like this:

```
agreement ~ correction * time + (1 + time|subject) + (1 + correction + time|item)
```

How do I get simple effects from the overall model?

I would like to compare all three levels of correction at time point 3, but taking into account the individual participant scores at time point 1 (a baseline measure). This would be kind of like an ANCOVA on time point 3 with baseline scores from timepoint 1 as the continuous measure.

I can do this:

```
library(lsmeans)

ref_levs <- emmeans(mod2, "correction", by = "time", at = list(time = "t3"))

pairs(ref_levs)
```

But I cannot have the output of the comparisons that controls for the individual participant scores at t1.

Am I forced to subset the dataset to have what I need, fitting a model like this one?

```
agreement_t3 ~ correction + time_t1 + (1|subject) + (1 + correction|item)
```

Or there is a way in emmeans to obtain that without having to subset the dataset?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "controlling for participant scores at time 1"? For example, do you want to look at change from time 1 to time 3? Or something else?

Comment: I mean that scores at time1 need to act as a covariate. So I want to look at changes in agreement at different correction levels (at time 3), but controlling for the variability in agreement at time 1 (taking into account the baseline variability in agreement). I think to do this I need to specify the model in the alternative way I indicated: "agreement_t3 ~ correction + time_t1". Basically, I need to subset my df `new_df <- filter(df, time == "t3")`, and add this as a new column to the new df: `new_df %<>% mutate(agreement_t1 = filter(df, time == "t1")$agreement)`
What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to fit a different model. But it seems to me it should still include `time` as a factor, with 2 levels (t2 and t3), but make a new variable (I'd call it `baseline`) with the response value at time 1. this will require re-shaping the data (perhaps the **reshape** or **reshape2** package may help, but it may be just as easy to do it manually). So the fixed-effects part of the model would be `agreement ~ baseline + correction * time`. I'm unclear as to why the random part needs to be quite as fancy as what you have, but maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it appears that you want to treat the observation at time 1 as a covariate, I will nonetheless show a reasonable way of estimating change from baseline with the model shown in the OP.

First, set things up so we have time as the primary factor, and obtain contrasts that compare times 2 and 3 with time 1:

```
emm1 <- emmeans(mod2, ~ time | correction)
emm2 <- contrast(emm1, "trt.vs.ctrl1, name = "time.gap")
```

Now, `time.gap` is a new factor with just the two levels t2 - t1 and t3 - t1. So you can now compare those changes:

```
pairs(emm2, by = "time.gap")
```

It's possible to do this in fewer steps: `contrast(emm1, interaction = c("trt.vs.ctrl1", "pairwise"), by = NULL)`; but I think the above is less confusing and easier to interpret.